# Excel VBA Array list

Tags: vba, excel

I am a toddler in VBA

I have a large range this could be more than 1000 text values (This could be going down A1), I am trying to concatenate all values with quote and comma into one cell (C1), i know of the transpose formula, but I am not sure my vba array will recognise this as a list.

I am keen for my array formula to recognize c1 as list, in order to carry out my action.

I am really keen to keep this clean and not use the concatenation and drag various formulas down.

I came across this, but this does not paste all the values into one cell.

```
Sub transpose()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim last As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet   
Set last = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
Set rng = ws.Range("A1", last)

For Each cell In rng
    Dim hold As String
    hold = """"
    hold = hold + cell.Value
    hold = hold + """" + ", "
    cell.Value = hold
Next cell

rng.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Code done by ryan E

If anyone can suggest any cheats on gathering list for Arrays that would be great. Other than using the Macro tool in excel

Example.

A1 = company1
A2 = company2
etc

Solution

C1 would show in one cell "company1", "company2", .... "company10000"

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean as a list in C1. Are you talking about some type of object like a ListObject (AKA Table) or rather just all the text values listed encapsulated by quotes and delimited by commas? If you're not familiar with the command there is the `JOIN` command in VBA that concatenates an array with delimiters. You can just grab the values from your range into an array and then join them and output to C1.

Comment: for Excel 2016 there is the [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function. Otherwise, you can copy the range and get the the text from the clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Join() and Transpose().

For example:

```
Sub transpose()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim last As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set last = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), last)

    ws.Range("B1").Value = """" & Join(Application.Transpose(rng.Value), """,""") & """"

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: now I see what you really want to do (create an array of sheet names to pass to `Sheets.Copy()`) here's one approach...

Add a sheet named (eg) "Groups" to hold your various lists of sheets to be copied:

[image]

Group names are in Row 1, with a list of sheets below each name.

Then use this code:

```
'to demo the "CopySheets()" sub...
Sub Tester()

    CopySheets "Group2" 'copy all sheets in Group2

End Sub


'Create of copy for all sheets under "GroupName" header...
Sub CopySheets(GroupName As String)

    Dim rng As Range, arr
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim f As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Groups") '<< has lists of sheet names

    'find the header for the group to be copied
    Set f = ws.Rows(1).Find(GroupName, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        'found the header, so create an array of the sheet names
        Set rng = ws.Range(f.Offset(1, 0), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp))
        arr = Application.transpose(rng.Value)
        'use the array in the sheets Copy method
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr).Copy

    Else
        'alert if you tried to copy a non-existent group
        MsgBox "Sheet group '" & GroupName & "' was not found!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Will this put it into one cell with quotes and comma

Comment: Isn't that what you're looking to do ?

Comment: Tim, thanks, I will have to try the code out tomorrow but thank you for help

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to run this final result, Sheets(Array(Range("B1").Value)).Copy can anyone share some light run time error 9

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to work.  What exactly are you trying to do with that line?  If you want to copy a bunch of sheets based on a list of sheet names then this wouldn't be a good approach.

Comment: I have a workbook with 60 sheets, and I recorded a macro, which gave me the idea of arrays and using lists when copying sheets into a new workbook. It worked fine when I quote and comma a list and put it in the array, but this is time consuming, as I have thirty variations to do. I wanted to make it dynamic.  I was going to use your code to quote and comma a list of sheets and plug it in a range value, which I hoped the VBA array would pickup and view it as a list of items concatenated as a string, but i am getting error messages, and pulling out my hair, any ideas???

Comment: See my edit above - I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Just so we are clear, so if I have list of 6 sheets in the array, I am keen for it to copy these 6 from the current population and than move it to a new workbook

Comment: I am trying this out now

Comment: I am trying this out now, I am little confused, am i using all three of your macro's or just the two in the bottom or just the one, and am I put in the ranges, ignore this comment i see what your doing

Comment: Just what's in the EDIT section.  "tester" is just an example of how you'd call the `CopySheets` sub - I have no idea what the rest of your workflow might look like, so that's just a small sub to show how you could call the main code with a list name.

Comment: I am getting Subscript out of range error, I have amended ("Groups")  with Group2 and added the sheet names below col b and its not working. Is this just creating the string, or copy sheets in a new workbook?

Comment: Sounds like you have a sheet name which doesn't exist in your workbook.    If you can share your workbook (via DropBox etc) I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Upload your workbook to a file-sharing service like Box, Dropbox, Google drive, etc etc, then post a link to the file

Comment: Do you have a linkedin account

Comment: I'd prefer not to use that.

Comment: I have a gmail account I prefer not to use that, as the link will show up my name. Supposing you open a new workbook, you have 10 sheets, if you are to select odd sheets, can you show me how your sub routine works. I used your concept and used your grouping technique, but writing the code and than concatenating the string element on a sheet and than copied the code from the spreadsheet to the vba script screen, this was quite time consuming

Comment: I'm not clear why you're still concatenating a string to do this?  If you don't want to use your gmail account you can sign up for a free Dropbox account, or any other filesharing platform...

Comment: Hi Tim I got your second method working, I also got the first method of  string concatenation working, but with the first method you have to copy from spreadsheet and paste it into the visual basic editor. This is for knowledge purposes but why does the array not recognise the concatenated line as a string, for the first method. I have been creating several seperate subs and than calling them.